# Nginx & fastcgi_cache_key. Adding token?

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx with an API. The access token is sent in the headers (either HTTP_X_ACCESS_TOKEN or PHP_AUTH_USER). I want to enable a 1 second fastcgi cache for identical requests from each user, but the default key,

```
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri;
```

could return another users response. I cannot see how I can add headers to the key to make it unique. Is this possible, or should I drop fastcgi cache for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the header to the key, e.g.

```
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$http_x_access_token;
```